# Not able to import json type files into a PostgreSQL database

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, couchbase

So I tried importing a json type file that I exported from my Couchbase Server bucket (database) into a PostgreSQL database. When I tried importing the file and at first it looked like it's gonna work and import properly but then I got the following message:

```
LOG: statement: COPY json.json_table FROM STDIN
ERROR: invalid input syntax for type json
DETAIL: The input string ended unexpectedly.
CONTEXT: JSON data, line 1: ...
```

The file that was exported from Couchbase was exported using the list format parameter. To give you a better understanding of what the whole process looked like in the terminal here's what commands I used:

```
./cbexport json -c "cluster_name" -u Administrator -p "password" 
-b "name_of_bucket" --scope-field "name_of_scope-field" --collection-field "name_of_collection-field" 
-o "path where the file is gonna be saved" -f lines -t 4
```

The Couchbase export was successful and when inspected, the file looked normal and 100% identical to what it looked like in the database it was exported from.

The only thing that comes to mind is that while I'm trying to import the json file into the postgres database, it adds a new row into the file which brakes the entire import process.

Does anyone have any idea what might be happening here? Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with Couchbase, but PostgreSQL's COPY will work on CSV data. So, your JSON data will need to be properly quoted as a string (so that they can be parsed).

For example, suppose we have a table `test1`:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test1 (id integer not null, body json);
```

And a file `test1.csv` with CSV data:

```
id,body
1,'{"a":199,"b":{"c":"Foo"}}'
2,'{"a":399,"b":{"d":"Baz"}}'
```

The following `COPY` (or `\copy` if importing from client-side) will import the data (`body` is a JSON column). Note the double-quoting to specify the character used for quoting text columns.

```sql
\copy test1 FROM 'test1.csv' WITH CSV HEADER QUOTE '''';
```

Comment: I tried populating a table within postgres with json type data and it worked when doing it from scratch, but the problem is I have 40 something thousand rows of data that I need to transfer over from Couchbase to Postgres

Comment: @MihaelKirin How does each record from Couchbase looks like? Can you post an example? I suppose that you can post-process those records (with text-editing tools like `sed`) and make them compatible to what PostgreSQL expects as CSV column input

Comment: It looks like a standard json type file (it basically has the same format). The reason for the whole import thing is to see if it's possible to migrate files from a NoSQL database (which in this case is the Couchbase Server) into one that is an SQL database (which in this case is PostgreSQL).

I forgot to address the first comment you posted, it did work with CSV type files (I've even tried importing them with different delimiters and all of them worked) but some of the files are saved in the json format.